# how can i get the value of a variable from a different form variable? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, image, radio-button, global-variables

im trying to make a game for a class on vb.net and i want the player to be able to change the car. im doing that by adding a picturebox and a button in the first form.

when you click the button, it takes you to another form with several radiobuttons (im experimenting so i only used 2) and there you can pick the color.

when you pick a color, a value is stored in a variable and i want to be able to get that value in the first form. but the image never changes when i go back.

i think the problem is when it comes to storing the variable and getting it in the other form, so i would appreciate some help with that. however, if you find some other mistake in the code, please help me out.

edit:i came to the conclusion that the problem is not with the variable. i think it might have something to do with the if structure.

here is form 1

```
Public Class Form1
    Public color2 As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        color2 = 0
        Form2.Show()
        Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        color2 = Form2.color

        If color2 = 1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ritac\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Visual Basic\teste.cor\teste.cor\Resources\153413201_357943841905712_3966209847925971836_n.png")
        ElseIf color2 = 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\ritac\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Visual Basic\teste.cor\teste.cor\Resources\153493631_1389827618051421_5894198564571460500_n.png")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

and here is form 2

```
Public Class Form2
    Public color As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            color = 1
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            color = 0
        End If

        Form1.Show()
        Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have a button that shows Form2 but not one to retrieve it's color value.  You only ever retrieve in on Form1's load.  As a simple test, add another button to Form1 that does nothing but this: `MsgBox(Form2.color.ToString)`.  Temporarily disable your Form2 hiding.  Run it, change the RB selection on Form2, and after each change, click the new button on Form1 to see the value of Form2.color.

Comment: @techonaut i was able to check if the value of the variable was going to form1 and it was. now i dont know what the problem is. not even my teacher can figure this out.

Comment: Please update your code to show where you know you are getting the value back OK, and the point where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show how **NOT** to use the default instance of Form2.  It also shows passing the instance of Form1 to the instance of Form2.  Give it a try.  The Stops are there for debugging.  They can be removed.

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Form2Instance As Form2

    Public FooVar As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ChkForm2()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ChkForm2()
        FooVar = Form2Instance.BarVar
        If FooVar = Integer.MaxValue Then
            Stop
        ElseIf FooVar = Integer.MinValue Then
            Stop
        ElseIf FooVar = 0 Then
            Stop
        Else
            Stop
        End If
        Me.Hide()
        Form2Instance.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChkForm2()
        If Form2Instance Is Nothing OrElse Form2Instance.IsDisposed Then
            Form2Instance = New Form2(Me)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Form1Instance As Form1

    Public Sub New(Frm1 As Form1)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Form1Instance = Frm1
    End Sub

    Public BarVar As Integer = Integer.MinValue

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            BarVar = Integer.MaxValue
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
            BarVar = Integer.MinValue
        Else
            BarVar = 0
        End If
        ShowForm1()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowForm1()
        Me.Hide()
        Form1Instance.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```